# NodeJs How to use moment-timezone to convert Epoch to Specific TImezone and format

Tags: node.js, datetime, timezone, momentjs

I have a use-case in which I want to convert an Epoch integer value into a specific Timezone time and a specific format,
Also, I want to convert a human-readable date time into epoch.

I am trying to use `moment-tz` for the timezone conversion.

I using a specific Epoch timestamp `1555296000` which is -
`Monday, April 15, 2019 10:40:00 AM` in Kuala Lampur Malaysia,
I am able to convert `2019-04-15 10:40:00` of `Asia/Kuala_Lumpur` timezone into correct Unix.

But I am unable to convert `1555296000` into another timezone's unix,
i.e I wish to convert `1555296000` into equivalent `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` of `Asia/Calcutta` timezone.

**Following is the code I'm trying to work with -**

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');

    console.log("Convert from Asia/Kuala_Lumpur to Unix -> ", moment.tz("2019-04-15 10:40:00","Asia/Kuala_Lumpur").unix());
// Outputs - 1555296000

console.log("Epoch to Specific TimeZone and Format -> ",moment(1555296000).tz("Asia/Calcutta").format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'));
// Outputs - 1970-01-19 05:31:36
// I want  - 2019-04-15 08:10:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out

```
const moment = require("moment-timezone");

console.log(
  moment
    .unix(1555296000)
    .tz("Asia/Calcutta")
    .format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
);
```

**2019-04-15 08:10:00 - "Asia/Calcutta"** is **2019-04-15 10:40:00 - "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"**

Comment: `HH`.  Not `hh`.

Comment: @MattJohnson Yes, missed it. hh is for 12 hours and HH is for 24 hours. Thanks for the catch.